# Semantics class causes overflow when wrap a expanded widget inside a column flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I need sort semantics route, i use the parameter sortKey attribute  of the semantics widget all ok but i have a column-> semantics-> expanded causes a overflow. I cant set a static height

[image]

```
Column(
            children: [
              Semantics(
                sortKey: const OrdinalSortKey(3),
                child: _OverlayHeader(
                  showSwipeIndicator: showSwipeIndicator,
                  onClosedPressed: onClosedPressed,
                  title: title,
                ),
              ),
              Semantics(
                sortKey: const OrdinalSortKey(1),
                child: Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: BdsSpacing.SPACE_S_2),
                    child: ListView(
                      key: const Key('bc-overlay-list_view-items_section'),
                      children: children ?? [],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Semantics(
                sortKey: const OrdinalSortKey(2),
                child: _ButtonsSection(
                  closeBtnLabel: closeBtnLabel,
                  onClosedPressed: onClosedPressed,
                  optionBtnLabel: optionBtnLabel,
                  onOptionBtnPressed: onOptionBtnPressed,
                  horizontalButtons: horizontalButtons,
                  isDarkTheme: _isDarkTheme,
                  overlayFoundations: overlayFoundations,
                  optionBtnEnable: optionBtnEnable,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
```

I need that talkback read in the order, show image to see the order

Answer (score 0):

`Expanded` needed to be on `Semantics`.

```dart
Expanded(
  child: Semantics(
    sortKey: const OrdinalSortKey(1),
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(),
      child: ListView(
```

You can also resort the children on column without having Semantics.